# Picking only one key value pair in jsonb column based on a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, contains, jsonb

I am trying to get the source and target where source is 270 and the column is jsonb and values like

```json
[{"source": 270, "target": 285}, 
 {"source": 427, "target": 285}, 
 {"source": 285, "target": 285}]
```

The expected output is `{"source": 270, "target": 285}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JSON path query:

```
select jsonb_path_query_first(the_column, '$[*] ? (@.source == 270)')
from the_table;
```

Comment: jsonb_path_query_first is not working in postgres version which I use. I am using

Comment: @Klaus: that's the reason you should always specify your Postgres version, especially if it's not the current one.

Answer (score 0):

It is working If I use the following Query. Here links is the column name.

select links from (select jsonb_array_elements(links) as links from supply_chain_graph) as foo where links->>'source'='270'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).